# Windows File Server Rebuild

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, file-sharing

I'm rebuilding a Windows file server for our corporate share.

Is there any reason to use Dynamic Disk over Basic Disk or is it better to just leave it as Basic?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks

Comment: I actually already read that one.  I had hoped for professional experience but I guess I should have stuck with Reddit and saved myself the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use dynamic disks, if you want, or need to use the older software RAID, and a maybe a couple other less common features.

You don't need dynamic disk if you are using storage spaces, or some kind of hardware based RAID, or just simple filesystems.

Some of the Microsoft documentation seem to strongly suggest you not use dynamic disks.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk

> Dynamic disks have been deprecated from Windows and we don't recommend using them anymore. Instead, we recommend using basic disks or using the newer Storage Spaces technology when you want to pool disks together into larger volumes.